# Image Overlay by div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have faced a difficult situation when it comes to a div transparent overlay on an image on my web, just like many others did, like the following

[Image Overlay](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/overlay.html)

My implementation method is exactly the same as the above mentioned, just one difference, my image is not just a single image, but a big image consist of 6 small images, they line up together to form a big square image, each small image has an URL attached. Just like the image below

[image]

I first set the parent div as relative and the 6 images absolute position, everything works pretty well but it comes to a problem that when I try to resize my browser (as I need to fulfill the mobile version), the overlay's position ran wrong.

And here is the actual code I am currently implementing

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 serMainDiv">
        <img class="material_shading img-responsive" src='<?php print get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/imgs/service_palette.png"?>'/>
        <!--overlay div-->
        <div class="overlayDiv" ng-click="serviceClick('family')"><span style="position:absolute;left: 35%;top: 38%;font-size: 20px;opacity: 0.8;font-weight: bold;">Family</span></div>
        <div class="overlayDiv2" ng-click="serviceClick('retire')"><span style="position:absolute;left: 35%;top: 38%;font-size: 20px;opacity: 0.8;font-weight: bold;">Retire</span></div>
        <div class="overlayDiv3" ng-click="serviceClick('happy')"><span style="position:absolute;left: 35%;top: 38%;font-size: 20px;opacity: 0.8;font-weight: bold;">serviceHappy</span></div>
        <div class="overlayDiv4" ng-click="serviceClick('wedding')"><span style="position:absolute;left: 35%;top: 38%;font-size: 20px;opacity: 0.8;font-weight: bold;">Wedding</span></div>
        <div class="overlayDiv5" ng-click="serviceClick('job')"><span style="position:absolute;left: 35%;top: 38%;font-size: 20px;opacity: 0.8;font-weight: bold;">Jobs</span></div>
        <div class="overlayDiv6" ng-click="serviceClick('single')"><span style="position:absolute;left: 42%;top: 38%;font-size: 20px;opacity: 0.8;font-weight: bold;">Single</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And each overlay class explictly state the position to fit for the position of the image

CSS

```
.overlayDiv2{
    width: 242px;
    height: 210px;
    top: 0;
    left: 298px;
}
```

And each div owns its corresponding position parameters.

Realizing the reason should be the fixed width and height of each overlay layer, I know I can make use of javascript to detect for every single screen dimension changes, but just want to ask if there are any smarter approach before kicking off using the realtime resize by Javascript

Thanks and appreciate for all the kind help!

Comment: Don't post just description. Post your tried code also.

Comment: What do want exactly to do?

Comment: @ketan Sorry for the lack of code shown, I have updated the code I have used, thanks!